# How does BerryBoot work?

Tags: boot, filesystem, berryboot

Good evening,
BerryBoot allows us to put multiple OSes on the same SD card, and I know it uses SquashFS, but I don't understand how everything is done.
I'd like more explanation about how do SquashFS and BerryBoot work.